# How I Add All category for all yearmonth wise data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-view

Here is my Query:-

```
;WITH Tenure
AS
(
    SELECT 
        T.[Employee ID],
        CASE WHEN [Datediff_] = logic THEN '0 to 1 Year'
             WHEN [Datediff_] = logic THEN '1 to 1.11 Year'
             WHEN [Datediff_] = logic THEN '2 to 2.11 Year'
             WHEN [Datediff_] = logic THEN '3 to 3.11 Year'
             WHEN [Datediff_] = logic THEN '4 to 4.11 Year' 
             ELSE 'More Than 5 Years' END AS [Tenure Grouping]          
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT [Employee ID],[Hire Date],[Last Working Day],
            CASE WHEN logic END AS [Datediff_]
        FROM [dbo].[Employee_]
    )AS T
)

,Headcount
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            FORMAT(T1.HireDate,'yyyyMM') AS [Month Year],
            T2.[Tenure Grouping],
            COUNT(T1.[Employee ID]) AS Headcount
        FROM [dbo].[Employee_] AS T1 WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Tenure AS T2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON T1.[Employee ID] = T2.[Employee ID]
)


SELECT * FROM Headcount
```

Result From this Query After RUN:-

| YearMonth | Tenure Grouping | Hiring |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 0 to 1 Year | 65 |
| 202101 | 1 to 1.11 Year | 49 |

But I want this Result:-

| YearMonth | Tenure Grouping | Hiring |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 0 to 1 Year | 65 |
| 202101 | 1 to 1.11 Year | 49 |
| 202101 | 2 to 2.11 Year | 0 |
| 202101 | 3 to 3.11 Year | 0 |
| 202101 | 4 to 4.11 Year | 0 |
| 202101 | More Than 5 | 0 |

**Note:- For all Year Month Column I need all the category. If there is no value then put '0'**.

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a dataset with all the values for `Tenure Grouping` (and `YearMonth`) first, that you can then `LEFT JOIN` from.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for response but in this way my count is not coming correct.